# Access another top-level JSON object with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json

Iam having a hard time accessing another top-level JSON object within my application.
The plan is to load data from Instagram (which works), but not to count the top-level I want.

The JSON document can be found here (http://pastebin.com/0Z4vBjRn) Basically it has three top-level objects: pagination, meta and data (where I want the data bit).

This is my code for now:

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


            // Viser "spinner" for å symbolisere nettverkstrafikk.
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

            // URL til JSON filen
            NSURL *newsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/beer/media/recent?client_id=client_key"];

            //URL Requestobjekt for å kontrollere tilkobling
            NSURLRequest *newsRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newsUrl];
            [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:newsRequest delegate:self];

        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
            [rawImages setLength:0];
            rawImages = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
            [rawImages appendData:data];
        }

        - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            images = [[NSArray alloc]init]; // Updated
            images = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rawImages options:0 error:0];
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
            UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Feil" message:@"Det har oppstått en feil ved nedlastingen av data. Dobbeltsjekk at du er koblet til internett" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Fortsett" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [errorView show];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        }





        - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
            return 1;
        }

        - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

            return [images count];

        }

        - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            UICollectionViewCelle *cell = (UICollectionViewCelle *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"eksempel.jpg"];

            return cell;
        }
```

Obviously the count part won't work (it only returns three). But how could I make it count all the objects within the "data" object?
All help are highly appreciated! I've done my Googling but I can't seem to find exactly what Iam looking.

Comment: -1 for doing this: `images = [NSArray array];`

Comment: Where is the `data` object?

Comment: Have you NSLogged `images`?

Comment: The data object is the 'rawImages'. I've also tried to NSLog it. Everything pops out, but obviously only the top-level elements get counted. Not the children of data which I want to.

Comment: Paste the relevant part of the JSON document here. It can't be accessed without an API key.

Comment: Hi! Here's a pastebin of the whole JSON response: http://pastebin.com/0Z4vBjRn
I'll add it to my main post aswell.
What I'd like to get out is the data (count them), and the images to display them.